Cannot receive an SMS response on an application I did using NetBeans
I have created an application using Java on NetBeans where a part of it is to send an SMS to specified numbers, the application sends the SMS successfully but when it comes to getting the response the application cannot receive any response. I am using Bulk SMS API and when I go the the inbox tab on Bulk SMS, I can see the responses but I cannot see any response on the application.
This is a snippet of what my code looks like:
package studentsupporttutoringsystem;

import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
    
public class SendSms {
        
    public void sms(String UserName, String password, String message,String to){
    
        try{
            
             // Construct data
            String data = "";
            /*
             * Note the suggested encoding for certain parameters, notably
             * the username, password and especially the message.  ISO-8859-1
             * is essentially the character set that we use for message bodies,
             * with a few exceptions for e.g. Greek characters.  For a full list,
             * see:  https://www.bulksms.com/developer/eapi/submission/character-encoding/
             */
            data += "username=" + URLEncoder.encode(UserName, "ISO-8859-1");
            data += "&password=" + URLEncoder.encode(password, "ISO-8859-1");
            data += "&message=" + URLEncoder.encode(message, "ISO-8859-1");
            data += "&want_report=1";
            data += "&msisdn=" + to;

            // Send data
            // Please see the FAQ regarding HTTPS (port 443) and HTTP (port 80/5567)
            URL url = new URL("https://api-legacy1.bulksms.com/eapi/submission/send_sms/2/2.0");
            URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
            conn.setDoOutput(true);
            OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
            wr.write(data);
            wr.flush();
            
            // Get the response
            BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
            String line;
            while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
            // Print the response output...
            System.out.println(line);
            wr.close();
            rd.close();
            
            }
                        
            if (line.toUpperCase().equals("ALT")){
            
                String UserN = "UserName";
                String PassW = "password";
                String Msg = "The tutor won't be available at this time. Please call them to schedule a suitable time for both of them";
                String Contacts = "Specified numbers";
                
                UserName = UserN;
                password = PassW;
                message = Msg;
                to = Contacts;
            }
             
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            
            System.out.println("");
        }   
      
    }
}

I tried using chatgpt to fix my code but still I still face the same problem.

Closing the BufferedReader in the while loop is probably not correct.
